# Paperclip image set within script tags shows the image text url not the image - expandablebanners.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, image, paperclip

I'm using [expandablebanners.js](http://www.expandablebanners.com/) on a rails site, the code I have to display the rollover image is;

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var roll_img = "<%= @advert.roll_img.url %>"
        var squarecenterbottom = ExpandableBanners.banner("squarecenterbottom", roll_img);
        squarecenterbottom.animated = true;
        squarecenterbottom.setDirection('down', 'center');
        squarecenterbottom.expandOnClick = false;
        if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){documentReady=true;});}
        else if (!window.onload) window.onload = function(){documentReady=true;}

      </script>
```

the main image is displayed on the page as so;

```
         <%= link_to image_tag(@advert.img(:horizontal) title: @advert.name,),
             @advert.target_url, :id => 'squarecenterbottom' %>
```

when you rollover the main image it should show the rollover image but
when I rollover the image it just shows the rollover image's url (i.e as text), I don't know what the problem is....

the code output is;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var roll_img = "http://localhost:3000/system/adverts/large_imgs/000/000/004/original/1n.jpg?1401967781"
        var squarecenterbottom = ExpandableBanners.banner("squarecenterbottom", roll_img  );
        squarecenterbottom.animated = true;
        squarecenterbottom.setDirection('down', 'center');
        squarecenterbottom.expandOnClick = false;
        if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){documentReady=true;});}
        else if (!window.onload) window.onload = function(){documentReady=true;}

      </script>
      <a href="www.example.com id="squarecenterbottom"><img alt="test22" height="90"  src="/system/adverts/imgs/000/000/004/horizontal/2n.jpeg?1401818651" title="test22" width="730" /></a>
  </div>
```

and this is the code from the documentation that shows how it works;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var squaretopleft = ExpandableBanners.banner("squaretopleft", "images/square_expanded.jpg");
    squaretopleft.setCloseImage("images/closebutton.jpg", 'left', 'top');
    squaretopleft.animated = true;
    squaretopleft.setDirection('up', 'left'); 
    squaretopleft.expandOnClick = false;

if (document.addEventListener) {
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){documentReady=true;});}
else if (!window.onload) window.onload = function(){documentReady=true;}
</script>
</head>

<body> 

<a id="squaretopleft" href="www.yourwebsite.com"><img src="images/square.jpg" /></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it seems that the issue comes from putting quotes around the definition of `roll_img` in the first line of the javascript code.  What else have you tried?

Comment: I'd try to make that line this: `var roll_img = <%= @advert.roll_img.url %>;`

Comment: Can you provide the output of the main image. ror code for main image should be the problem.

Comment: @JakeSmith the url needs to be passed as a string, that's why it's in quotes

Comment: @OnurYıldırım I've added the image output to the question

Comment: There is one quotation mark too many in your output. The image tag is a part of a string, not an actual tag. The `id =` should not be a part of the href, it should be outside of it... Try using `image_tag(@advert.img(:horizontal) title: @advert.name,).html_safe`

Answer (score 0):

This might be a path or HTML structure problem.
Things to check:

1. In your output, your `<a>` element comes right after `<script>`. Then there is a `</div>` closing tag. Do you have an opening `<div>` before all? Are they all in the `<body>`?
2. Since `ExpandableBanners` code sets up `onload` and `DOMContentLoaded` listeners, try moving that in the `<head>` of the document.
3. Your original image has **.jpeg** extension and roll image has **.jpg**. Nothing wrong with this but make sure you have the correct images (and extensions) in the right paths. e.g. original image is under `/imgs` folder and roll is under `/large_imgs`. Is this ok?
4. Try relative path for your roll image. In this case: remove `http://localhost:3000` in the beginning. (Assuming your original image is showing ok.)

Comment: 1. yes there is a div before and everything is in the body, 2. moving to head made no difference, 3.images have the correct paths and show correctly when used normally, 4. with or without absolute urls doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Few points:

- Missing semicolon at the end of `var roll_img...` declaration
- As Ruby Racer mentioned, the generated anchor tag is missing double quote `<a href="www.example.com`